# Applying the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem to show the existence of a limit cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Show that there exists a limit cycle by finding a positive invariant set
>    $$y'' = -y + y'(1-3y^2-2y')^2$$

I rewrote this second order ODE as a system of two first order ODE's

$y_1' = y_2$ and $y_2' = -y_1 + y_2(1-3y_1^2-2y_2)^2$

Then I rewrote the system in polar co-ordinates:

$r' = r\sin^2\theta(1-2r^2\cos^2\theta-2r\sin\theta)^2$ and
$\theta' = 1 + \sin\theta(1-3r^2\cos^2\theta-2r\sin\theta)\cos\theta$

Then I used the fact that $0 \leq \sin^2\theta \leq 1$ to get $0 \leq r' \leq r(1-2r^2\cos^2\theta-2r\sin\theta)$ and then the fact that $0 \leq \cos^2\theta \leq 1$ to get $$r(1-2r\sin\theta)^2 \leq r' \leq r(1-3r^2 -2r\sin\theta)^2$$ and then I used the fact that $-1 \leq \sin\theta \leq 1$ to get $$r(1-3r^2 + 2r)^2 \leq r' \leq r(1-2r)$$

From here I'm not sure how to proceed to find this positive invariant set. The solutions to this question state that the positive invariant set is given by $$D = \left\{ r \ : \frac{1}{3} \leq r^2 \leq \frac{1}{2}\right\}$$

And I'm not sure how to arrive at that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The task as reproduced has to be wrong. There has to be a typo either in the original task or in its transmission to the question. In the given version, one gets, as observed, that $\dot V\ge 0$ everywhere, using $V=y^2+y'^2$. Furthermore, there is no radius with $\dot V<0$ on the whole circle of that radius, as required for the existence of a trapping, or positive invariant annulus, so that there are no closed orbits and thus no limit cycles.

---

With a slight modification, exchanging the closing parentheses and the square to
$$
y''+y=y'(1-3y^2-2y'^2)
$$
one gets
\begin{align}
\dot V=\frac{d}{dt}V(y(t),y'(t))=\frac d{dt}(y'^2+y^2)
&=2y'(y''+y)
\\
&=2y'^2(1-3y^2-2y'^2)\\[1em]
&=2y'^2(1-3(y^2+y'^2)+y'^2)\tag{1}\\[1em]
&=2y'^2(1-2(y^2+y'^2)-y^2).\tag{2}
\end{align}
This is (1) non-negative for $V=y^2+y'^2\le\frac13$ and (2) non-positive for $V=y'^2+y^2\ge\frac12$. Thus a solution will move up resp. down the level curves of the squared radius function $V$ when outside the interval $$\frac13<V=r^2=y^2+y'^2<\frac12.$$

---

That the claim follows this easily from the modified task hints strongly that this is the original version and the one in the question the erroneous one.

[image: solution curves for both variants]

The code for the first picture is

```
def f(u,t): y,v=u; a=1-3*y**2-2*v**2; return [v, v*a-y]
tspan = np.linspace(0,10,150);
N=6; units = [ np.array([ np.cos(u), np.sin(u) ]) for u in 2*np.pi/N*np.arange(0,N) ];
radii = np.linspace(0.4, 0.8, 8+1);
for r in radii: plt.plot(r*np.cos(tspan),r*np.sin(tspan),lw=0.2)
for u0 in units: 
    sol = odeint(f, radii[ 1]*u0, tspan); x,y=sol.T; plt.plot(x,y,'b');
    sol = odeint(f, radii[-2]*u0, tspan); x,y=sol.T; plt.plot(x,y,'g');
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

Comment: First line it should be a square ...$(1-3y^2-2y')^2$ you put the exponant inside the paranthesis Lutzl

Comment: @Isham : Yes. The task as written is wrong, the claim can not be true, as OP nearly wrote down. While my modification almost trivially gives the claim. Now what has more chance of being the original text book problem?

Comment: Thats possible yes that there is a typo in op exercice...Things like that happen ..of course..I find personnaly your answer inspiring...so I think you should keept it there I upvote your answer for this reason...

Comment: Hey, Why does $1/3 < V <1/2$ imply there is a periodic cycle?

Comment: Because that defines a trapping region with no other stationary/equilibrium points. Any solution that enters this region never leaves and thus has to approach some limit manifold. @Diger

Comment: So based on the poincare-bendixson-theorem, or how is the precise argument?

Comment: I mean, how do you know there is no other stationary point? What about $y=0$?

Comment: If the point is inside the annulus, $y=0$ implies $y'\ne 0$, so that there can be no stationary point on that axis. In the other direction, $y'=0$ implies $y=0$ for a stationary point, which is not inside the annulus. @Diger