# Prove that $\ddot{x}+(2x^2+\dot{x}^2-1)\dot{x}+x=0$ has a periodic solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that $\ddot{x}+(2x^2+\dot{x}^2-1)\dot{x}+x=0$ has a periodic solution.

Here's my partial solution: Let $\dot{x}=y$. Then $\ddot{x}=\dot{y}=-(2x^2+y^2-1)y-x=-2x^2y-y^3+y-x$.

So we have $\dot{x}=y$ and $\dot{y}=-2x^2y-y^3+y-x$.

Convert to polar coordinates:
$r\dot{r}=x\dot{x}+y\dot{y}=xy+y(-2x^2y-y^3+y-x)=xy-2x^2y^2-y^4+y^2-xy$.

$r\dot{r}=-2r^4cos^2\theta sin^2\theta-r^4sin^4\theta +r^2sin^2\theta$ which reduces to

$\dot{r}=-2r^3cos^2\theta sin^2\theta-r^3sin^4\theta +rsin^2\theta$.

Now I don't know how to proceed to deduce that we have a periodic solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I would say that $x(t)=0$ is a periodic solution.

Comment: I don't think you can deduce anything just from $\dot{r}$... what's $\dot\theta$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Poincare-Bendixson theorem or do you have to do manual analysis of $\dot{r}$ and $\dot{\theta}$ to prove this?

Comment: For a similar task see [Applying the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem ... $y''+y=y'(1-3y^2-2y'^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2796981)

Comment: Yes, we can use Poincare-Bendixson Theorem. I think I solved it. For $r=1, \dot{r}<0$ and for $r=\frac{1}{2}, \dot{r}>1$ so the annulus region between $r=\frac{1}{2}$ and $r=1$ is where the periodic orbit exists. Please verify if that is correct.

Comment: I see the regions $2x^2+\dot x^2-1<2r^2-1<0$ and $2x^2+\dot x^2-1>r^2-1>0$ as those with clearly visible radius dynamic, so you missed a square root.

Comment: Your ODE is precisely what is called the Lienard equation. In the third edition of Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations by Jordan and Smith, on page 402, Theorem 11.2 gives four  simple conditions under which there is at least one nontrivial periodic solution. Proof pages 402-404, nice example on page 404

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

$$
\cases{
\dot x_1 = x_2\\
\dot x_2 = -x_1-(2x_1^2+x_2^2-1)x_2
}
$$

or

$$
\cases{
\dot x_1 x_1= x_1x_2\\
\dot x_2 x_2= -x_1x_2-(2x_1^2+x_2^2-1)x_2^2
}
$$

adding the equations

$$
\frac 12(x_1^2+x_2^2)' = -(2x_1^2+x_2^2-1)x_2^2
$$

Comment: Not really familiar with this. Do you mind explaining why this shows periodicity? If I do the same algebra with the equation $\ddot{x}=-x$, then I would obtain $\frac{1}{2} \left(x_1^2 + x_2^2\right)' = 0$, and now? Why does this show periodicity?